# Home Page design for a File repository

Tags: gui-design, responsive-design, homepage

The product is a file repository / publishing software that is managed by admins. Admins add file and reports, that can be promoted to the landing page carousel or to their respective folder based on the categories.

The previous designer suggested a count for all the dashboards and reports added. While I had to think about the design on Tablet. Because tablet has more real estate, I suggested showing the latest files and reports. Image below 
[image]

The UX maturity of the organization is low and most stakeholder will argue are expecting a pig with a lipstick.

**What I want to achieve**:

- Show newly uploaded files and reports.
- Show recently accessed files
- Be consistent accross Desktop, Mobile and Tablet

What would be a better way to show show something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on the requirements you gave:

[image: File Repository/Publishing App Mockup for Desktop]

And on tablet:

[image: File Repository/Publishing App Mockup for Tablet]